# supevisorのWebコンソールに別名を出したい

Tags: python, supervisord

supevisorのWebコンソールを使用しています。

デフォルトですと、/etc/supervisord.confファイルでprogramに設定したものが
そもまま出てしまいますので、
そこを別名にして、日本語などを使用することは可能でしょうか？
そのまま、programを直接日本語などを入力しても文字化けしてしまい不可能でした。

[image: Webコンソールです]
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: heliac2001さんコメントありがとうございます。

コメントアウトされていて、

`;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)`

がありました。これを使えばできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x シリーズでは unicode 文字列と ascii 文字列(正しい呼称か不明)が別のモノ(オブジェクト？)として扱われますので、それに合わせた変更を行う必要がありました。以下に記載する方法は対症療法で、根本的な解決にはなっていません。つまり、Supervisor のバージョンアップなどで無効になる可能性が高いと考えて下さい。

---

Supervisor には `web.py` というファイルがありますが、これを一部変更する必要があります。私の方の環境は、

- Ubutu Linux 12.04
- Python 2.7
- Supervisor 3.0b2 (apt でインストールした package)

となっていて、`web.py` のパスは以下です。

`/usr/share/pyshared/supervisor/web.py`

ユーザのローカルディレクリにインストールした場合には `$HOME/.local` 以下などに置かれているかもしれませんので、適宜見つけて下さい。

以下が変更用のパッチになります。

```
--- web.py.org  2013-07-19 12:30:58.000000000 +0900
+++ web.py  2015-01-31 14:55:42.482416837 +0900
@@ -203,7 +203,7 @@
         root = self.clone()

         title = root.findmeld('title')
-        title.content('Supervisor tail of process %s' % processname)
+        title.content('Supervisor tail of process %s' % processname.decode('utf-8'))
         tailbody = root.findmeld('tailbody')
         tailbody.content(tail)

@@ -426,7 +426,7 @@
         if message is not None:
             statusarea = root.findmeld('statusmessage')
             statusarea.attrib['class'] = 'status_msg'
-            statusarea.content(message)
+            statusarea.content(message.decode('utf-8'))

         if data:
             iterator = root.findmeld('tr').repeat(data)
@@ -445,7 +445,7 @@
                 processname = make_namespec(item['group'], item['name'])
                 anchor.attributes(href='tail.html?processname=%s' %
                                   urllib.quote(processname))
-                anchor.content(processname)
+                anchor.content(processname.decode('utf-8'))

                 actions = item['actions']
                 actionitem_td = tr_element.findmeld('actionitem_td')
```

これを、例えば `supervisor_utf-8.patch` として保存して、以下を実行します。

```
$ cd [directory where web.py exists]
$ cp -pv web.py web.py.org
$ patch < supervisor_utf-8.patch
```

# 質問者様の環境が UNIX 系でない場合には手動でパッチを当てていただくことになります

それから、Supervisor が Web コンソールで使用しているテンプレートファイル(HTML)に `charset` を設定しておいたほうが良いかと思います。以下では `UTF-8` としていますが、適宜変更して下さい。

対象ファイル:

```
/usr/share/pyshared/supervisor/ui/status.html
/usr/share/pyshared/supervisor/ui/tail.html
```

追加内容:(`meta http-equiv=...` の部分)

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Supervisor Status</title>
              :
</head>
```

また、Supervisor から起動されるプログラム(プロセス)にもロケールを設定しておいた方が良いでしょう。以下は `ja_JP.UTF-8` としていますが、同様に適宜変更して下さい。

対象ファイル:

```
/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

追加内容:(`environment=...` の部分)

```
[supervisord]
environment=LANG='ja_JP.UTF-8',LC_ALL='ja_JP.UTF-8'
```

---

Supervisor UTF-8 patch 適用後のウェブコンソール

[image: Supervisor UTF-8 patch 適用後]